# base_url for creating routes for menu in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is many similar post but non of them solved my problem.

When i use `base_url()` in `href` attribute, i'm getting wrong url - `http://localhost/admin/localhost/admin/insertData`.

My `config.php` script -> `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost';`, and also i have removed `index.php` from url.

So as we can see, `<a href="<?=base_url();?>admin/insertData"></a>` solution only concatenate current `url` with `href` attribute.

Also i have tried setting `$config['base_url'] = '';`, but then im getting: `http://::1/admin/insertData`
and this solution also didn't work.

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|assets|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any suggestion how can this be fix?

Comment: To `base_url()` you should assign full value of both PHP_URL_SCHEME and PHP_URL_HOST i.e. `http://localhost/` (ending with trailing slash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use base_url(); except I desperately need it. I leave that empty `$config['base_url'] = '';` and I use root path like:

```
<a href="/admin/insertData"></a>
```

Comment: I tried this and when you press more times in the same button, url is chenged to `http://localhost/admin/admin/insertData` and 404 error appear. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you using form or it is a simple href?

Comment: I am using simple href, `<a href="admin/insertData"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Insert Data</a>`

Comment: what are the contents of your .htaccess file?

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|assets|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: use <a href="/admin/insertData"> not <a href="admin/insertData">

Comment: Oh, that was the solution! Thanks alot!

Comment: @UsmanAhmed if using codeigniter 3 not good idea to leave base url empty.